# Java and references

Tags: java

I have basic class :

```
 public class SomeClass {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }   

}
```

In a method I have this code :

```
private void test(){

    SomeClass sc1 = new SomeClass();
    sc1.getList().add("a");
    sc1.getList().add("b");

    SomeClass sc2 = sc1;

    System.out.println(sc2.getList().size());

    sc1.getList().remove(0);
    System.out.println(sc2.getList().size());

    sc1=null;
    System.out.println(sc2.getList().size());

    sc2=null;
    System.out.println(sc2.getList().size());


}
```

I receive :

- 2
- 1
- 1
- NullPointerException

but I though I would received :

- 2
- 1
- NullPointerException
- NullPointerException (if previous NullPointerException caught)

If a referenced object is set to `null`, the reference link is broken ? Thank you for clarifications

Comment: Note that you never set an *object* "to `null`". `null` isn't an object, it's a reference. Hence, you set references (such as variables, object attributes, slots in collections) to `null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If a referenced object is set to null, the reference link is broken ?

There's no such concept as setting an *object* to null, You can only set a *variable* to null. This statement:

```
sc1=null;
```

... changes the value of `sc1` *and that is all*.

A variable is simple a storage location with a name. The storage location has a value, and for variables whose type is non-primitive, that value is a reference. It's *very* important to understand that the value of the variable is *not* an object. It's just a reference.

So this statement:

```
SomeClass sc2 = sc1;
```

just declares a new variable (`sc2`) which starts off with the same value as an existing variable (`sc1`). The two variables are completely separate - they just happen to have the same value to start with.

I like to think of variables as pieces of paper. A piece of paper can have some primitive value on it, such as a number, or it can have a house address<sup>1</sup>. Imagine these steps:

- Build a house
- Write the address of that house on a piece of paper (`sc1`)
- Copy the writing on `sc1` onto another piece of paper (`sc2`)
- Rub out the address on `sc1`
- Visit the house whose address is on `sc2`

That's similar to what you're doing here... and clearly rubbing out the value on `sc1` doesn't affect either the house or the `sc2` piece of paper.

Now as for why you see 2 and then 1... imagine these steps:

- Build a house
- Write the address of that house on a piece of paper (`sc1`)
- Use `sc1` to find the house, and put two parcels on the doorstep
- Copy the writing on `sc1` onto another piece of paper (`sc2`)
- Use `sc1` to find the house, and shout out how many parcels you find
- Use `sc1` to find the house, and take one parcel away
- Use `sc2` to find the house, and shout out how many parcels you find

The first time you'll shout 2, and then you'll shout 1. You're not changing the values on the pieces of paper - you're changing the house itself, by adding or removing parcels.

---

<sup>1</sup> I know that references aren't memory addresses necessarily. This is purely for the sake of the analogy, which is one I've found helpful.

Comment: that's why i think we need gc.+1

Answer (score 5):

When you set `sc2` to `sc1`, you *copy* the reference. The two variables reference the same object, *but they do not become the same variable*. Setting `sc1` to `null` does not change `sc2` - it references the same `SomeClass` object, so there is no `NullPointerException` when you access its `getList()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you make `SomeClass sc1 = new SomeClass()`, you make something like `sc1->OBJECT`. Doing `sc2=sc1`, is like making `sc2->sc1->OBJECT`, or `sc2->OBJECT`. So changing sc1 references doesn't change sc2.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just take a look where things point:

```
SomeClass sc1 = new SomeClass();
```

Here you have sc1 pointing (has a reference to) to your newly created class and sc2 is not even in picure.

```
SomeClass sc2 = sc1;
```

You have both sc1 and sc2 pointing to same object.

```
sc1=null;
```

Your object is still intact since sc2 is still pointing to it. Sc1 is null and not pointing to anything. Object itself is not eligible for garbage collection because of sc2.

```
sc2=null;
```

Now you have both sc1 and sc2 pointing to nothing. Your object has no references to it and garbage collector will (eventually) release it.

As you see from step-by-step, "reference link is broken" but object it self is not really affected until all its references are lost. As long as you have single reference to it, object is alive.